# Programatically calling a method on a abstract class, which is stored in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have a dictionary like this, it holds all the packet events.

```
Events = new Dictionary<short, Func<ISession, IIncomingPacket, ICoreContext, Task>>
{
    {IncomingPacketIds.HandshakeRequest, HandshakeRequest.Handle }
};
```

Each packet files are all the same, as they follow the interface.

```
public abstract class HandshakeRequest : IAsyncPacket
{
    public async Task Handle(ISession session, IIncomingPacket packet, ICoreContext coreContext)
    {
         // TODO
    }
}
```

All that `IAsyncPacket` interface does is force a Handle method.

```
public interface IAsyncPacket
{
    Task Handle(ISession session, IIncomingPacket packet, ICoreContext coreContext);
}
```

So my main question is, in that first dictionary I have. Is there a way to just pass in the class, and have it programatically call the Handle method, as it seems redundant typing it when its always the same.

Here is how I'm currently executing the value of that dictionary:

```
if (Events.TryGetValue(packetId, out var packetEvent))
{
    await packetEvent.Invoke(session, packet, _coreContext);
}
```

Not only would it improve the code, it would also make it much simpler to use, force the class to always follow the interface properly, and make the dictionary easier to work with.

Comment: I'm having trouble following the thread of your question. You have a dictionary of functions, but you'd rather have a dictionary of objects? Could you provide some clarification for what the end-result should look like?

Comment: I want a dictionary of short (key), IAsyncPacket (value). It would just make it easier to specify only a class, instead of having to specify the method name too, the interface forces that anyway.

Comment: OK, so then my question is, what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: The code doesn't compile.   `Handle` is an instance method, not a static method, so you need to specify an *object instance* to create a delegate for that method, not a type.

Comment: The title really says it all, I'm unsure how to programmatically call a method on a class, although the answers specific to this question as its using a dictionary, and not just calling any function hard coded.

Comment: @fskdjwe why use a `Func` for this?  Make your dictionary a `Dictionary<short, IAsyncPacket>`.  Then just call your method like this `someDictionary[0].Value.Handle(session, packet, coreContext)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, but here is what it sounds like you are looking for:

```
Events = new Dictionary<short, IAsyncPacket>()
... (code to load dictionary) ...

...
if (Events.TryGetValue(packetId, out IAsyncPacket p))
{
    await p.Handle(session, packet, coreContext);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what wasn't understood about the question, but the answer is spot on.

Comment: You sure did just that.